# 1064: SQL syntax (MySQL INSERT)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

To Start.. I am using mysqli_real_escape_string() on every text field, and leaving INT as they are:

The following query successfully inserts the record into the table without fail, every field is correctly stored... There has to be something I'm being glib about, I have blurry coding eyes at this point... But after the INSERT statement is run, mysqli_error($con) tosses the following error:

1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

(I'm nearly 100% certain I do not even use the number 1 at all, whether it be in the php code or a value)

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO hj_media 
        (mediaID,MedDropID,MediaName,GLCode,Store,MediaType,MiscDetail,ArtDueDate,RunDate,EndDate,AdvMonth,Size,Dimensions,TotalCost,HJShare,CoOpShare,Vendor,HamiltonFiscal,VendorFiscal,AdDescription,Category,AddedtoVCM,ArtworkRequested,InvoiceProcessed,BilledVendor,NetCost,ProductionCost,CostPiece,QuantityOrdered,HJCostPrinting,Postage,DDFee,EventDescription,EventDate,DateToPrint,DateInMail,DateInHome,TotalPrintQuantity,TotalMailFile,TotalActualMail,ReturnedPieces,SalesResultsUnits,SaleResultsDollars,SpendNonPrint,SpendPrint,SpendAdvertising,SpendPR,MediaNameOther,ClientPersona,Campaign) 
        VALUES(NULL,$add_medid,'$add_vehicle',$add_glcode,'$add_loclist','$add_type','$add_miscdetails','$add_artdate','$add_rundate','$add_enddate','$add_month','$add_size','$add_dimensions','$add_totalcost','$add_hjshare','$add_coopshare','$add_vendor',$add_hamiltonfiscal,$add_vendorfiscal,'$add_addescription','$add_category','$add_addedtovcm','$add_artworkrequested','$add_invoiceprocessed','$add_billedvendor','$add_netcost','$add_productioncost','$add_costperpiece',$add_quantityordered,'$add_hjprintcost','$add_postage','$add_ddfee','$add_eventdescription','$add_eventdate','$add_datetoprint','$add_dateinmail','$add_dateinhome',$add_printquantity,$add_totalmailfile,$add_totalactualmail,$add_returnedpieces,$add_salesunits,'$add_salesdollars','$add_spendnonprint','$add_spendprint','$add_spendadvertising','$add_spendpr','$add_medianameother','$add_persona','$add_campaign')");

if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
    echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: 1) use prepared statements to avoid these problems and for security. 2) your database appears to be in desparate need of normalization

Comment: Please tell me your input strings

Comment: I have tested it with the simplest of data strings.  The INT values I set to 5, and the String values I set to the letter A.  Produces the same successful entry but reports an error.

Comment: Oh, and for the date fields. I used 2000-02-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED QUERY, TRY THIS**

```
           $query="INSERT INTO hj_media 
          (mediaID,MedDropID,MediaName,GLCode,Store,MediaType,MiscDetail,ArtDueDate,RunDate,EndDate,AdvMonth,Size,Dimensions,TotalCost,HJShare,CoOpShare,Vendor,HamiltonFiscal,VendorFiscal,AdDescription,Category,AddedtoVCM,ArtworkRequested,InvoiceProcessed,BilledVendor,NetCost,ProductionCost,CostPiece,QuantityOrdered,HJCostPrinting,Postage,DDFee,EventDescription,EventDate,DateToPrint,DateInMail,DateInHome,TotalPrintQuantity,TotalMailFile,TotalActualMail,ReturnedPieces,SalesResultsUnits,SaleResultsDollars,SpendNonPrint,SpendPrint,SpendAdvertising,SpendPR,MediaNameOther,ClientPersona,Campaign)  ";

            $query.=" VALUES(NULL,$add_medid,'$add_vehicle',$add_glcode,'$add_loclist','$add_type','$add_miscdetails','$add_artdate','$add_rundate','$add_enddate','$add_month','$add_size','$add_dimensions','$add_totalcost','$add_hjshare','$add_coopshare','$add_vendor',$add_hamiltonfiscal,$add_vendorfiscal,'$add_addescription','$add_category','$add_addedtovcm','$add_artworkrequested','$add_invoiceprocessed','$add_billedvendor','$add_netcost','$add_productioncost','$add_costperpiece',$add_quantityordered,'$add_hjprintcost','$add_postage','$add_ddfee','$add_eventdescription','$add_eventdate','$add_datetoprint','$add_dateinmail','$add_dateinhome',$add_printquantity,$add_totalmailfile,$add_totalactualmail,$add_returnedpieces,$add_salesunits,'$add_salesdollars','$add_spendnonprint','$add_spendprint','$add_spendadvertising','$add_spendpr','$add_medianameother','$add_persona','$add_campaign');";


              $result =mysqli_query($con,$query);

                         If($result){
                              echo "Success"';
                           }
                          else{
                               echo " query failed ". mysqli_errno();
                          }
```

Comment: That worked! thank you!  Just for my knowledge... was it a spacing (white space) issue?

Comment: the problem was in in the VALUES clause if you noticed, it has to end with a closing  **);**  but it ended with  **);"** if you just copied and pasted

Answer (score -1):

The problem is yoir sending a boolean gotten from the first query test  into another mysqli query function. It's a good thing to have set a variable that refernces your query string, so that you use but this value in the **mysqli query**  function . **Try this**

```
             $query="put your myqli query here;";
             $result =mysqli_query($con,$query);

             If($result){
                  echo "Success"';
               }
              else{
                   echo " query failed ". mysqli_errno();
              }
```

**can you knidly thick the question answered if this solves your problem ?**

Comment: You can also make a function called confirm_query that performs the action of returning to this caller a value or string. That's instead of echo you have return and  the function  takes a bool and make sure the values your setting corespond and has the type specified in the field

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts... though I'm still reporting the same error with the code change mentioned.